¿Cómo puedo crear usando pivot por cantidad de columnas en función de la diferencia de 2 fechas en SQL Oracle?
En esta consulta:
select start_date, END_DATE ,round(abs(END_DATE - start_date))as diferencia from evento

puedo generar la diferencia entre 2 las dos fechas que contengan mis dos columnas seleccionadas; pretendo usar un pivot para que me cree nuevas columnas en función de la diferencia que me genera ambas fechas.
Ejemplo:
Tengo start_date 01/05/2024 & 05/05/2024: la diferencia serían 4 días y la columna mostraría un 4. El pivot que quiero implementar requiero que genere x cantidad de columnas conforme la diferencia (teniendo en cuenta que por ejemplo puedo tener 365 columnas por la diferencia de dos fechas, sí podría llegar a suceder y comprendo que no es óptimo)
¿Cómo podría implementar el pivot?
Dejo lo que tengo estructurado:
select start_date, END_DATE ,round(abs(END_DATE - start_date))as diferencia 
from (
    select start_date from dual
    select end_date from dual
    select round(abs(END_DATE - start_date))as diferencia from dual
)evento
pivot(
    sum(diferencia) 
    for diferencia_dias in (start_date, end_date)
);


La consulta que publicas como ejemplo no creo que pueda usarse de base y más que aclarar lo que buscas, crea algo de confusión. Creo que sería mejor que le des clic en [edit] e incluyas en tu pregunta un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida que esperas producir con ESOS datos de entrada.
